# Wildly incorrect Lat/Long from UTM conversion

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3

I set up a project using the WGS 84/ UTM zone 17N [EPSG:32617] for my location in Ohio, where the AOI's Lat / Long is around 41.616139, -82.707090.

As I have seen when selecting the CRS, that part of Ohio is WGS 84 / UTM Zone 17N.

[image: QGIS CRS selection]

I created 8 points in a layer with EPSG:32617 using a Google satellite basemap, also on [EPSG:32617], and then exported to a CSV that looks like this, with the UTM coords:

```
X,Y,id,
-9206983.45574504,5103663.18575966,"1"
-9206982.43007245,5103659.42496019,"2"
-9206981.74629073,5103655.32226985,"3"
-9206980.54967271,5103651.21957952,"4"
-9206979.52400013,5103648.48445263,"5"
-9206978.49832755,5103644.55270772,"6"
-9206977.64360039,5103641.30474454,"7"
-9206976.10509152,5103637.37299963,"8"
```

The goal is to export that as a CSV but with Lat / Long instead of UTM coords.  For that export I specified EPSG:4326 to get the coords in Lat / long, and ended up with this in lat / long, a location SW of the Hawaiian Islands:

```
X,Y,id,
-153.231053524158,17.324457565269,"1"
-153.231040434255,17.3244500073122,"2"
-153.231027386234,17.3244406302462,"3"
-153.231012886373,17.3244325873277,"4"
-153.231002574535,17.3244278183346,"5"
-153.230989021638,17.3244197955119,"6"
-153.230977804728,17.3244131872912,"7"
-153.230962799987,17.3244064986058,"8"
```

When I right click on the AOI in QGIS I get the coordinates in the attached pic, right around the coords I get in the table above.

[image: QGIS screenshot]

How can I get this straightened out?

A good start would be to have the correct coords displayed with a right-click on the canvas. I just don't understand how to get the "real" latitude / Longitude for my AOI.

Am I using the wrong CRS? Something is off-kilter but I just don't know what it is.

Obviously the UTM coords are wrong, yielding just more incorrect Lat / Long conversions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those points are in [EPSG:3857](https://epsg.io/3857) (WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator) not EPSG:32617 (WGS 84/ UTM zone 17N).

EPSG:3857 is the CRS of the Google satellite basemap.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Lon, Lats are:

```
X,Y,id,
-82.7077395893134,41.6162192323632,"1"
-82.7077303755397,41.6161939752203,"2"
-82.707724233024,41.6161664219622,"3"
-82.7077134836215,41.6161388686924,"4"
-82.7077042698479,41.6161204998393,"5"
-82.7076950560744,41.6160940946038,"6"
-82.7076873779296,41.616072281575,"7"
-82.7076735572693,41.6160458763198,"8"
```

Google map link for the 1st point https://goo.gl/maps/by9woCtM9odbZjt86

Comment: Thank you for that, @user2856!  I had been using these other CRS's to get the straight down view ie. EPSG:4326.

Comment: It works great for me now, @user2856!  

I had been using these other CRS's to get the top down view ie. EPSG:32617 that "straightens out" when you zoom into my AOI, or EPSG:4326 that is always a top down view.

Is there a way to get a straight down view while preserving the actual coordinates reported from the canvas?  

For my needs the angled view of EPSG:3857 is OK (it's gonna have to be), but there may be some situations where a fully top down view may offer a better perspective for plotting points.
  
Thanks,  Bill

Comment: You can set your project to EPSG:32617 for display. You can create the points in any CRS you want.  If you want lon/lat output, create a new layer and specify EPSG:4326 when you create it.  Your project will still display in  32617 but when you add a new point using the editing tools QGIS will translate it to 4326 when it stores the geometry.

Comment: I followed your guidance and set up a new project with EPSG:32617, and a google satellite base map with that CRS, and zoomed into my AOI.

I created the points in a new layer in EPSG:4326, and when I exported I also specified EPSG:4326 as the layer CRS for the CSV file, and I got the correct Long / Lat coords in the X,Y fields!

When I right-clicked on the canvas to Copy Coordinate, I saw the Map Coordinate as EPSG:32617 and below that saw the EPSG:4326 Long / Lat coordinate as being correct, I knew it was gonna work out.

357720.202,4608573.265
41.61620274,-82.70773662

Thanks,  Bill